# Como adicionar navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Já adiconei o navigation drawer em meu projeto, só que preciso adicionar botão de menu na action bar, como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: vai precisar usar um Toolbar, é facil.

Comment: @Icaro, você tem algum exemplo ou tutorial que possa me indicar?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Exemplo de uso ta toolbar com navigation Drawer

É um exemplo do livro do Ricardo Lecheta

https://github.com/icaronunes/Carro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/livroandroid/carros/activity/MainActivity.java

https://github.com/icaronunes/Carro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/livroandroid/carros/activity/BaseActivity.java

https://github.com/icaronunes/Carro/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Esses três arquivos fazer o funcionamento.

Veja principalmente o BaseActivity e o activity_main.xml